# Why are the header, container, and navbar divs above the ul div?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am having trouble with positioning for the ul div.  I tried floating it to the left to position it there.  But it went underneath the header, container and navbar div.  And the divs are all entirely above the ul div.  Why?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="header">

    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">NAV1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NAV2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NAV3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you may need to read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context and https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ :)  (overflow:hiden, or float:left; or display:table or elsse from your reading applied to header will fix the behavior of header and wrap the floatting child

Answer (score 0):

> If a parent element contains nothing but floated elements, its height collapses to nothing.

**solution:**

> Method 1) `overflow: auto;`

```
.navbar {

    width:100%;

    border: 2px solid green;

    overflow: auto; 

}
```

> Method 2) Use of `:after`pseudo

```
.navbar:after {

        display: block;

        content: '';

        clear: both;
}
```

**Full code :**

```css
    html {
        height:100%;
    }

    body {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        background-color: grey;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    #container {
        width:80%;
        margin:auto;
        height:auto;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    #header {
        width:100%;
        border: 2px solid blue;

    }

    .navbar {
        width:100%;
        border: 2px solid green; 
         overflow: auto; 

    }

    ul {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        float:left;
    }

    li{
        display:inline;
        font-size:20px;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="container">
           <div class="header">

              <div class="navbar">
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">NAV1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">NAV2</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">NAV3</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </div>

               </div>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use float property, the parent height will not see its height. So in your case, the header div (and above parent) has height=0px (if you don't use any padding properties). So for this, you need to set `<br clear='both;'>` after ul tag. Then it will work normally.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="header">

    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">NAV1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NAV2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NAV3</a></li>
      </ul><br clear='both'>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```